# Whats the characteristic/personality of one that rewards those who treat him well, while punishing others who don't?

Tags: single-word-requests, personality

I'm looking for a word instead of a phrase to describe this, thanks!
Greedy and Selfish don't really fit for what I'm looking for.

Comment: How about using the word "adjudicator"?

Comment: The dictionary says "make a formal judgement on a disputed matter; act as a judge in a competition; pronounce or declare judicially." Which isn't too relatable to my question.

Comment: Please provide the context where you would use the word.

Comment: It's one characteristic of [narcissist](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjRy4aYy6XuAhUzFjQIHcq_C30QFjAHegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mayoclinic.org%2Fdiseases-conditions%2Fnarcissistic-personality-disorder%2Fsymptoms-causes%2Fsyc-20366662&usg=AOvVaw2kAd1T24og4q4ZrqSRbP21).

Comment: The person could be a [**control freak**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/control_freak) or an [**emotional blackmailer**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/emotional_blackmail).

Comment: They reciprocate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Such a person is *partial*

> *partial* = inclined to favor one side over another
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partial)

> *Partial* - Someone who is partial supports a particular person or thing, for example in a competition or dispute, instead of being completely fair.
>
> [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/partial)>

They may also be described as

> *one-sided* = only considering one opinion in an argument in a way that is unfair
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-sided)

They are also showing *favouritism*, but I cannot find an adjective corresponding to this noun.

> *favouritism* = the practice of giving unfair preferential treatment to one person or group at the expense of another.
>
> [Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/favouritism)

All these defintions contain thoughts of unfairness, corresponding to your example, where one is treated unfairly (by excess punishment) compared to the other (by excess reward).

Comment: I don't think this quite answers the question, which does not provide the required context anyway.

Comment: I feel that my answer is very well complemented by @fev

Answer (score 0):

Such a person is called ***discriminatory*** or ***biased***.

[WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/discriminatory.html) defines ***discriminatory*** as

> Making or showing an unfair or prejudicial distinction between different categories of people or things, especially on the grounds of race, age, or sex

In your description, the person shows an unfair distinction on the basis of whether people treat him well or not.

> e.g. I think it was also ***discriminatory*** against those who do not
> own a sense of humor.

Here is an example with ***biased*** (which means to exhibit bias, prejudice for or against one person or group):

> Examined from the learner's point of view, the standard approach is heavily biased against beginning students. (See [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/biased.html) for more examples)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, as in someone who treats others in direct correlation to how those people threat them, I would say it's called being reciprocal.

To quote Merriam-Webster:

> Given or felt by each toward the other; mutual:

> Reciprocal respect.
> Given, performed, felt, etc., in return:

> Reciprocal aid.
> Matching; corresponding; equivalent: